# Why does the formulation of my code influences my outcome whilst mathematical it is the same?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I wrote a code and it finally works and it produces a desired outcome. However if a make a minor change to my code, if I do not define the `u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4, u_d` values seperately but put them directly into the `du1dt, du2dt, du3dt, du4dt, duuddt` equations, my outcomes change drastically. In terms of mathematics this should not make a difference, why does it in python code?

```
def myFunction(r,t):
    g = 9.81
    L_L = 20
    L_r = 20
    L_d = 60
    u_s = 0.08
    w_d = 4


    u_1 = r[0]
    u_2 = r[1]
    u_3 = r[2]
    u_4 = r[3]
    u_d = r[4]
    p_1 = r[5]
    p_2 = r[6]
    p_3 = r[7]
    p_4 = r[8]
    deltap_L = r[9]
    deltap_R = r[10]
    w_r = r[11]
    w_L = r[12]


    du1dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L + deltap_L/L_L) - (u_1)
    du2dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - (u_2)
    du3dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r - deltap_R/L_r) - (u_3)
    du4dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - (u_4)
    duddt =  (- g*((p_3-p_2)/L_d)) - (u_d)

    u_1 = (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L
    u_2 = (w_d*u_d)/w_L
    u_3 = (w_L*u_2)/w_r
    u_4 = (L_r*u_s + w_r*u_3)/w_r
    u_d = (w_r*u_3)/w_d

    dp1dt =  - u_1
    dp2dt = - u_1
    dp3dt = + u_4
    dp4dt =  + u_4
    ddeltap_Ldt = - u_1
    ddeltap_Rdt = u_4 

    dwrdt = -u_s
    dwldt = u_s



    return (du1dt, du2dt, du3dt, du4dt, duddt, dp1dt, dp2dt, dp3dt, dp4dt, ddeltap_Ldt, ddeltap_Rdt, dwrdt, dwldt)

r0 = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20])
t = np.linspace(0,250,1000)
r = odeint(myFunction, r0, t)



u1 = r[:,0]
u2 = r[:,1]
u3 = r[:,2]
u4 = r[:,3]
ud = r[:,4]
p1 = r[:,5]
p2 = r[:,6]
p3 = r[:,7]
p4 = r[:,8]
deltapL = r[:,9]
deltapR = r[:,10]
wR = r[:,11]
wl = r[:,12]
```

With the minor change it would be:

```
def myFunction(r,t):
    g = 9.81
    L_L = 20
    L_r = 20
    L_d = 60
    u_s = 0.08
    w_d = 4


    u_1 = r[0]
    u_2 = r[1]
    u_3 = r[2]
    u_4 = r[3]
    u_d = r[4]
    p_1 = r[5]
    p_2 = r[6]
    p_3 = r[7]
    p_4 = r[8]
    deltap_L = r[9]
    deltap_R = r[10]
    w_r = r[11]
    w_L = r[12]


    du1dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L + deltap_L/L_L) - ((L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L)
    du2dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - ((w_d*u_d)/w_L)
    du3dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r - deltap_R/L_r) - ((w_L*u_2)/w_r)
    du4dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - ((L_r*u_s + w_r*u_3)/w_r)
    duddt =  (- g*((p_3-p_2)/L_d)) - ((w_r*u_3)/w_d)

    dp1dt =  - u_1
    dp2dt = - u_1
    dp3dt = + u_4
    dp4dt =  + u_4
    ddeltap_Ldt = - u_1
    ddeltap_Rdt = u_4 

    dwrdt = -u_s
    dwldt = u_s



    return (du1dt, du2dt, du3dt, du4dt, duddt, dp1dt, dp2dt, dp3dt, dp4dt, ddeltap_Ldt, ddeltap_Rdt, dwrdt, dwldt)

r0 = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20])
t = np.linspace(0,250,1000)
r = odeint(myFunction, r0, t)



u1 = r[:,0]
u2 = r[:,1]
u3 = r[:,2]
u4 = r[:,3]
ud = r[:,4]
p1 = r[:,5]
p2 = r[:,6]
p3 = r[:,7]
p4 = r[:,8]
deltapL = r[:,9]
deltapR = r[:,10]
wR = r[:,11]
wl = r[:,12]
```

How come? It makes me doubt my first code in general.

Answer (score 1):

In first function you are putting value of u_1 directly which is r[0] at that time.
so calculation of 'du1dt' is based on that value. Then after you are changing value of u_1 to (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L.

Whereas in second in function you have used value (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L for the value u_1 for calculating du1dt. That's why you are getting different values.
Same follows for u_2 and other variables

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I am trying to simulate is the behaviour of u1 over time (du1dt). However, u1 at a certain time also needs to suffice (L_L *u_s(t) + w_L(t)*u_2(t))/w_L(t). The same for u2, u3 etcetera. I'm having a hard time programming this.

Comment: @Iris : What do you mean "needs to suffice"? How can a number suffice a number? And if you mean that as a system of simultaneous non-linear equations, what influence does the input have?